# Linux Mint Settings Changed Automatically

Tags: configuration, linux-mint

The settings for my linux mint OS have somehow changed automatically. The wallpaper has changed to default background, the mouse and touchpad settings are different, and I can't see the 'Computer' icon on my desktop either. I've tried restarting a couple times and in some restarts I've seen this message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda4: clean, 270358/1144640 files, 2372070/4574707 blocks (check in 3 mounts)
* Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon[74G[ OK ]
* Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
* Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
* Starting load fallback graphics devices[74G[ OK ]
* Starting Userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping load fallback graphics devices[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
* Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]
* Starting save udev log and update rules[74G[ OK ]
* Starting configure virtual network devices[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping save udev log and update rules[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping configure virtual network devices[74G[ OK ]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Checking for running unattended-upgrades:
* Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
* Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
* Starting LightDM Display Manager[74G[ OK ]
* Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
* Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[74G[ OK ]
* Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
* Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
* Starting deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping Userspace bootsplash[74G[ OK ]
* Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Provide some more environmental info. Are you logging in as the `root` user by any chance? By `"... somehow changed automatically ..."` you mean you haven't touched configuration at all? Nothing happens **automagically** unless you e.g. did a system upgrade or changed something.

Comment: I'm dual booting with mac os. I was working on mac and I just restarted my computer to switch to linux. When I logged in, I noticed that these settings had changed. Also, if I try to change those settings back to original ones, the changes won't save. I've had linux mint for a month now and this is the first time I've seen this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it be reinstalling KDE and removing GNOME from the terminal, so I ended up with KDE at its original settings. Another option is to try and make some changes in the config file in a temp folder.